# python selenium xpath multiple button using javascript issues

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

i'm currently facing issue with selenium getting the exact xpath on a javascript button and appreciate if someone could enlighten me or guide me.

As you can see from the image, the highlighted ones are the javascript button. what i'm planning to do is to use selenium to find buttons that are showing "bill" and click into it to clear the status.

[image: testing]

my current codes are

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[12]/a[1]")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[12]/a[1]").click()
```

What i want it to do is to search for the "bill" button and if is not found, keep refreshing the page until "bill" button appear, then click on it which will bring it to another page. Do take note that it can be more than 1 "bill" button appearing (still have not figure out how to code for that part as well but i would want it to click on the row that appear the "bill" button with the earlier timing first which will bring to another page and after clearing on that page which will forward back to this page and proceed with the 2nd "bill" button etc.)

what happen now with my code is that the xpath element is only on the first row of "bill" button which it also can be "check" button being on the first row at the same position. And like i mention earlier on there could be multiple "bill" button coming so i'm not sure how to solve for that.

this are the html i get from inspecting from chrome browser for the "bill" button.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showContent('billing','/info/bill/12');" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-card">
                                    </span>
                                    &nbsp;bill
                                </a>
```

Really really appreciate if someone can help me out on this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your XPATH has been copy pasted. That should have worked since every XPATH is unique but let me show another way for declaring XPATH.

Try declaring XPATH in this format //tag_name[@attr1="value1" and @attr2="value2" and...and @attrn="valuen"].  In your Example:

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' and @href='javascript;']")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' and @href='javascript;']").click()
```

You Can also validate whether your XPATH is unique or not by searching the XPATH in your console. Click Ctrl+F in console and copy paste your XPATH. If the number of results is 1, it's fine. Else, try adding more attributes to your XPATH.

Also check in the console whether the control of the button stays with a or wrapped in another tag. If it is wrapped within another tag, then you might have to change the XPATH.

Comment: Hi Sarath, 

thank you for helping out on my question! however my button for "remarks", "check" etc all have the same class. so if i use the method of your xpath, wont it be capturing all the buttons? is there anyway to just capture the "bill" buttons? possible to make xpath with those attribute you mention and adding another attribute with text that is call "bill"? may I how do i go about with the code if it can work that way? thanks!

Comment: If all your buttons have the same class then it would be a herculean task to get only the particular button. In my experience, I haven't been able to use my XPATH format for onclick attribute. Since, you have mentioned the word "My button " in your comment, I assume that this is your own webpage. So try adding unique ids and names to your button. By this way, the XPATH format would be uniquely identified. Thanks

Comment: Also this is another way by which you can access multiple buttons for common buttons. Use find_elements_by_xpath instead of find_element_by_xpath and use indexing to specify the button. In your example,  Let's say you search in console and the number of buttons having same attributes are "remarks","check" and "bill" respectively, Then you can capture the bill button by using driver.find_elements_by_xpath[("<XPATH FORMAT>")[2].click(). I find this method better than the one said above!